# Debug mode exits before hitting main with "Error: Could not load igc library"

Tags: c++, crash, qt-creator, alglib

I tried to import ALGLIB to my Qt creator C++ project, which is probably big.

The .exe compiles fine both in release and debug mode, and if I go to the debug and release directory, these .exe files run perfectly fine. I can also run the program in release mode inside Qt creator.

However, when I try to run it in debug mode, I get "*Error: Could not load igc library*" immediately, and the program exits without hitting main.

I was running with MinGW32 On Windows 10. The Qt version is 4.9.1 (Enterprise), and the `.log` file for debug is empty.

What does this error mean?

Comment: Maybe you do not have the igc library in debug mode. There should be a separate .dll for debug modus.

Comment: Thanks. But I am not sure this should be a library that is supposed to be inside the debug file. Becasue I can run the .exe in debug file. Or are you referring to something else by saying "library in debug mode". By the way what is igc library anyway.